# redirect input string from dialog's --inputbox to stderr

Tags: bash, dialog, stdout, stderr, whiptail

[Dialog's](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) --inputbox option does the following:

> On exit, the input string will be printed on dialog's output.

But how can I separate the input string from all those ANSI color codes that get printed to stdout? Or can I tell dialog somehow to write the input string to stderr?

Answer (score 0):

`dialog` does write the entered message to stderr, so you can redirect it something like this:

```
ans=$(dialog --inputbox "hello" 5 30 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

This will make the message be captured by the [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) and stored in `ans`. While the dialog is showed in the terminal (`/dev/tty`)